# Using existing SSH connection to connect to remote host

Tags: go, ssh

I was previously using [asyncssh](https://asyncssh.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#asyncssh.SSHClientConnection) for python. It has a feature that you can provide an already available connection to connect to a new host. I am looking into the ssh documentation. I don't see any option that can do this trick, not sure if I have to do some tunneling manually.

What I want is to connect to a machine using SSH that has auth, then use that connection to connect to another machine that has different auth then the first machine.

```
ncmConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            "xyz",
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password("xyz!"),
    },
}

routerConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
    User:            "xyz1",
    HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
        ssh.Password("xyz2"),
    },
}
ncm := "1.1.1.1"
router := "2.2.2.2
conn, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", ncm+":22", ncmConfig)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

# how can I use the conn to connect to a new machine.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conn2, err := conn.Dial("tcp", router+":22")
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

conn3, chans, reqs, err := ssh.NewClientConn(conn2, router+":22", routerConfig)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}

conn4 := ssh.NewClient(conn3, chans, reqs)
```

conn4 is the new connection.